# How do we know SymmetricAlgorithmNames::AesCbc is 128 bit or 256 bit in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I am using SymmetricAlgorithmNames::AesCbc and SymmetricAlgorithmNames::DesCbc algorithms in my Data Encryption implementation in WinRT.

I need to **ensure that these algorithms are at least 128 bit algorithms** which is not evident from the algorithm names. The same is evident if we are using OpenSLL (eg. EVP_aes_**128**_cfb128()).

Can anyone tell me **whether SymmetricAlgorithmNames::AesCbc is 128-bit or 256-bit or something other**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if you look at the example code for [OpenAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm.ASPx), you will see that it specifies the key length in one of the other method calls (`CreateSymmetricKey`).

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm automatically uses whatever size key you provide it. When you call `SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.CreateSymmetricKey` and pass in an `IBuffer` as `KeyMaterial`, whatever is contained in that `IBuffer will determine the bit length of your encryption. If you pass in 16 randomly-generated bytes, that will be (16*8) 128-bit, symmetric encryption. If you pass in 32 bytes, that will give you 256.

As it says in the spec, you can use `CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom` to get some secure, random bytes.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi Nate,
       Thanks a lot for clear description. It's very helpful.